# cannot remove a toolstrip white space

Tags: c#, winforms

I add a `ToolStrip` control to a forms and docking it to Top. My problem is I can't remove a white shadow from the `ToolStrip`. I even tried to paint all around the `ToolStrip`but it does not work. How can I do that.

Here is some of my code :

```
private void toolStripEx1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Red)), e.ClipRectangle);

}
```

and this does not work neither with a custom rendrer.

```
protected override void OnRenderToolStripBorder(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ToolStrip.GetType().Name != "toolStripEx1")
    {
        base.OnRenderToolStripBorder(e);
    }
}
```

[image: attached Screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# ToolStrip is transparent but border is still visible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245929/c-sharp-toolstrip-is-transparent-but-border-is-still-visible)

Comment: @Sinatr this not my case. because i don't know if it is really a border or something else like 3D effect for example.